# Trouble with js files connecting to my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting my js files to connect to my html pages.  I am using jquery and a premade lightbox .js file.  When I pull up chrome console, it's saying the files are not found, and I'm positive they are directed properly.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: what error do you get in your browser developer tools?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `/` at the start of the path.

Change it to `<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>` and similarly for everthing you are including tn your `html`

Comment: Ive done that, still getting an error for missing files

Comment: for which file are you getting error make sure you do a hard refresh after making changes

Comment: Clear browser cache and then refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can put dot before slash like below or remove the slash

```
<script src="./js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using absolute paths. That doesn't work here. Just remove the leading slash `/` in front of your script source paths. Afterwards it should work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a "**.**" in your script tags, for ex.

```
<script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`, same applies to lightbox